# How can Views and ViewModels utilize claims-based authorization in MVC 5?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-identity, claims-based-identity, asp.net-authorization

In my project I have implemented ASP.NET Identity 2.x with claims based authorization plus authentication.
I have added added support for a claims authorization attribute [as described here](http://leastprivilege.com/2012/10/26/using-claims-based-authorization-in-mvc-and-web-api/).

Here are the claims I'va come up with that would allow/disallow CRUD on employees.

```
public class ResourceClaimTypes
{
    public const string CreateEmployee = "urn:company:Employee:Create";
    public const string ReadEmployee = "urn:company:Employee:Read";
    public const string UpdateEmployee = "urn:company:Employee:Update";
    public const string DeleteEmployee = "urn:company:Employee:Delete";
}
```

An action would look like this:

```
    [ClaimsAuthorize( ResourceClaimTypes.ReadEmployee )]
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }
```

What I don't quite understand is how to make use of those claims in a **view and its view model**.
For instance, there is a view for displaying employees, which is a simple grid.
Then there are views for **editing** and **creating** employees.

What the view and view model should be capable of doing now is hiding or showing the Save/Update/Delete buttons according to the user's claims.

**Approach on the views:**

**Index ->** should display all employees if ReadEmployee claim is present, otherwise the view should still be accessible, but with a message "No premission to view employees".

**Create/Edit ->** the user should still be able to nvaigate to these views, but the "Create"/"Save" buttons should not be visible.

**Delete ->** all "Delete" buttons should be hidden.

Bottom line is, views should be accessible, but the Create/Save buttons should be **hidden.**

How can that be done?

*** UPDATE / MY SOLUTION ***

This is how I ended up doing it. 
Following Derek's suggestion I have used Action/Resource based authentication. Along with ASP.NET Identity I have implemented the IUserClaimStore interface to grab the claims from the DB.

**The Views and ViewModels (!) do NOT contain ANYTHING like CanRead, CanWrite!** 
I am using KendoUI and have created an extension method for buttons.

Inside the extension method I can access the custom ResourceAuthorizationManager (see blog from Dominik Baier). So when creating the button, I can call HttpContaxtBase.CheckAccess(...) to determine if the button should be enabled/visible, or not.

The only thing I need is a way to tell the extension method what action/resource combination to check access for.

Razor Example:

```
@Html.LinkButton(Action.Create, Resource.Employee)
```

This is all that is needed in the view to display (or not) a button that says "Create" and points to the Create view of the Employee controller.
Very clean, IMHO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should look at a product of Dominic Baier at Thinktecture for something like this.

The following article will explain how to achieve what your looking for quite elegantly.

http://leastprivilege.com/2014/06/24/resourceaction-based-authorization-for-owin-and-mvc-and-web-api/

They have example in there Git Hub repo.

** EDIT **

Here is the link to the GitHub Example you need to follow.

https://github.com/IdentityModel/Thinktecture.IdentityModel/tree/master/samples/OWIN/ResourceAuthorization/Chinook

Comment: Yes I have read many of Dominik's posts but have not see this one. I am using ASP.NET Identity and implement IClaimsStore<T> myself, which is where I added claims stored in the DB. Will this still work with the action/resource based approach above? Thank you.

Comment: Its been a while since I've looked into this, but i see no reason why it wouldn't work. Give it a try. Its agreat approach for me, you can unit test your resources. Are you using Cookies?

Comment: Yes ,cookies. What I'm missing in their sample is what I was asking in my original question: how can ViewModels and Views make elegant use of the authorization? I get the part with the controller/action, but I need to hide/show buttons in the View depending on the claims. Thanks again.

Comment: Your missing a part. In the views you can wrap content, such as buttons in a CheckAccess() method. There a full working example on GitHub. For example, a list of items, you can check access per item in the list I'll see if i can find it. And post the link.

Comment: Thanks again for your time. I can use CheckAccess in the views, though I would much rather populate properties in the ViewModels instead of having code in the View? Another part I am missing is how CheckAccess method in their sample knows to allow editing for album ID=1... I don't see who gets to decide that album 1 is indeed editable. Thanks.

Comment: The logic for checking access, and who gets to edit an item, is determined inside the ResourceManager class.  You can check the users claims for each item in the list. Get the Example Chinhook project building and step through it. Its really easy to setup. Im not sure trying to pump access properties into a View Model is a good idea.

Comment: Now I see it. So I would derive from the default ResAuthMan and somehow inject a claims service/repo that would give me the claims for a given user. Then I can react to that. I assume the ResAuthMan would live in the Infrastructure layer and not the web app? Thanks Derek.

Answer (score 1):

You have access current user's claims everywhere in your project and views are not an exception. Simply cast current user's identity to `claimsIdentity` to access user's claims:

```
var claims= ((ClaimsIdentity)HttpContext.Current.User.Identity).Claims;
```

You could write an extension method for this also:

```
public static bool CanEdit(this IIdentity identity)
{  
     return identity.IsAuthenticated
        && identity is ClaimsIdentity
        && ((ClaimsIdentity)identity).HasClaim(x =>
            x.Type == "EditClaim" && x.Value == "true");
}
```

Then you could easily write this code:

```
if(HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.CanEdit())
{
    //your code
}
```

But even you could check claims in views directly, consider check claims in your controllers and send simple true or false values by view models to your views for better approach.

Since we do not want mix our logic to views. It is much better to check privileges in controller instead. Consider this:

```
class PrivilegesViewModel
{
    public bool CanEdit{get;set;}
    public bool CanRead{get;set;}
    // and so on
}

class PostViewModel
{
    // our model data
    public PrivilegesViewModel Privileges{get;set;}
}
```

And in your controller:

```
public ActionResult Edit(int id)
{
    PostViewModel model=_postManager.Get(id);
    model.Privileges=new PrivilegesViewModel
    {
        CanEdit=HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.CanEdit(),
        // and so on
    }
    return View(model);
}
```

Now in your view just check bool values;

```
@if(model.Privileges.CanEdit)
{
    // print the button
}
```

Comment: You should really just set a property on the Model from the Controller and inspect the Model in the view rather than having the view call out to other code

Comment: @TrevorPilley I did not say call this on view. I just pointed out claims are accessible out side of attributes. Of course it is much better to check claims in controllers and send result as a view model to view.

Comment: I was referring to this line "But even you could check claims in views directly"

Comment: @TrevorPilley actually in this line I tried to warm reader to not use this in view and encouraged reader to use in controller instead.

Comment: @SamFarajpourGhamari Thanks for your reply. I am already checking the claims on the controller actions. I am not sure I understand "check claims in your controllers and send simple true or false values by view models". What does that mean? Can you explain further? Thanks.